# How do I disable media players indicators integration?

Tags: gnome, banshee, music

I recently moved from win7 to a linux distro so im not sure how exactly things work. What i found weird is while playing music with banshee and after hitting the "X" (close) button, the music that was playing in banshee didnt stop (i also tested this with beatbox getting the same result).

Does this have anything to do with MPRISv2 and is there a way to fix this?

For the record im using Ubuntu 12.04 + Gnome 3.4 + gnome shell + gnome-extensions-mediaplayer-indicator

Comment: The X closes the window but it doesn't *quit* the software, Rhythmbox for example when you close the window it gets sent to the background so the music won't stop, but if you pause it and then you close the window Rhythmbox exits. The music players usually have a Quit menu entry under File or Control+Q.

Comment: I have edited the title a bit so that it reflects your true request, edit it further if you think it's not what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will play - you have to hit the play button where the sound is. On the right hand side, look for where you see the sound icon.

Open it up - you will see that you can make the sound louder and softer, under that you will see a play button and a left and right button with an arrow in - that is to go to the next song and back to the previous song.

Hit the play and pause button will stop the sound and that is it. Nothing more to do, only when you open up a music play - you will only see you library and can then quickly go to a song you like...

That is the way to stop music completely so that you won't play in back.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I assumed it myself the reason why it keeps playing thats why i mentioned MPRISv2 and the mediaplayer indicator but, ultimately what im asking is how to disable that functionality and make banshee stop playing music after i close it

Comment: Do you know how to disable that integration? Can you add that to your answer?